# Offsets are different onTap and OnDrag - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have an image in which certain items are there which have starting offsets and their height and width, corresponding to each item in images I have different text, I have to drag the text and drop it to the correct position on the image,I am getting different offset while tap to particular location and while drag also I am getting different offsets. How can I get the same offsets?

Here is my code and image I am using. these are the details of Tree

```
x=673
y=635
h=214
w=149
```

with respect to image.
 [image]

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ImageInfo _imageInfo;
  AssetImage assestImage;
  double dx;
  double dy;
  Offset dragOffset;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assestImage = AssetImage('assets/hospital.jpg');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((a) => _getImageInfo());
  }

  void _getImageInfo() async {
    Image image = new Image.asset('assets/hospital.jpg');
    image.image
        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      _imageInfo = info;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            DragTarget(
                onAccept: (Offset dragOffset) {},
                builder: (
                  BuildContext context,
                  List<dynamic> accepted,
                  List<dynamic> rejected,
                ) {
                  return TapImage(
                    onTap: (Offset offset) {
                      print('Offset on Tapping the image is $offset');
                      dx = offset.dx * _imageInfo.image.width;
                      dy = offset.dy * _imageInfo.image.height;
                      if (_imageInfo != null) {
                        print('Image clicked: ${dx.toInt()} x ${dy.toInt()}');
                        if ((673 <= dx && dx <= 822) &&
                            (635 <= dy && dy <= 849)) {
                          print('you drop in tree');
                        } else {}
                      }
                    },
                    image: assestImage,
                  );
                }),
            Draggable(
                dragAnchor: DragAnchor.pointer,
                onDragEnd: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    dragOffset = details.offset;
                  });
                  print('dragoffset in onDrag Method is  $dragOffset');
                },
                data: dragOffset,
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(
                      'Tree',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                    )),
                feedback: Container(
                  height: 10.0,
                  child: Text(
                    'Tree',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef void OnTapLocation(Offset offset);

class TapImage extends StatelessWidget {
  TapImage({Key key, this.onTap, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  final OnTapLocation onTap;
  final ImageProvider image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _onTap(details, context),
      onLongPress: () {},
      child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/hospital.jpg')),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(TapDownDetails details, BuildContext context) {
    RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
    Offset local = getBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    print('locla ois $local');
    onTap(Offset(local.dx / getBox.size.width, local.dy / getBox.size.height));
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess the image is of dynamic size (depending on the screen size, scale settings, ...). You would need to get the size of the image and calculate the image position from the offset and image display size.

Comment: Okay will try to get the size of image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its working for me

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ImageInfo _imageInfo;
  AssetImage assestImage;
  double getheight;
  double getywidth;

  Offset dragOffset;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    assestImage = AssetImage('assets/hospital.jpg');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((a) => _getImageInfo());
  }

  void _getImageInfo() async {
    Image image = new Image.asset('assets/hospital.jpg');
    image.image
        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      _imageInfo = info;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TapImage(
            onTap: (Offset offset, RenderBox getBox, TapDownDetails details) {
              double dx;
              double dy;
              dx = offset.dx * _imageInfo.image.width;
              dy = offset.dy * _imageInfo.image.height;
              setState(() {
                dragEnd(dx, dy);
              });
            },
            image: assestImage,
          ),
          Draggable(
              dragAnchor: DragAnchor.pointer,
              onDragStarted: () {
                WidgetsBinding.instance
                    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
                          RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
                          getheight = getBox.size.height;
                          getywidth = getBox.size.width;
                        }));
              },
              onDragEnd: (details) {
                double dx;
                double dy;
                dx = (details.offset.dx / getywidth) * _imageInfo.image.width;
                dy =
                    ((details.offset.dy) / getywidth) * _imageInfo.image.height;
                setState(() {
                  dragEnd(dx, dy);
                });
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.0),
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(
                      'tree',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
                    )),
              ),
              feedback: Container(
                height: 10.0,
                child: Text(
                  'tree',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  void dragEnd(double dx, double dy) {
    if (_imageInfo != null) {
      if ((673 <= dx && dx <= 822) && (635 <= dy && dy <= 849)) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return _textDescriptionDialog(
              context,
              'Drag on tree',
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return _textDescriptionDialog(
              context,
              'Drag outside',
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _textDescriptionDialog(BuildContext context, String text) {
    return new FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? 0.5
            : 0.8,
        widthFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? 0.8
            : 0.4,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(20.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(child: Center(child: Text(text))),
        ));
  }
}

typedef void OnTapLocation(
    Offset offset, RenderBox getBox, TapDownDetails details);

class TapImage extends StatelessWidget {
  TapImage({Key key, this.onTap, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  final OnTapLocation onTap;
  final ImageProvider image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _onTap(details, context),
      child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/hospital.jpg')),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(TapDownDetails details, BuildContext context) {
    RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
    print('size is ${getBox.size}');
    Offset local = getBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    print('local is $local');
    onTap(Offset(local.dx / getBox.size.width, local.dy / getBox.size.height),
        getBox, details);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make new Widget then get local render box size. Something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  NetworkImage _networkImage;
  ImageInfo _imageInfo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _networkImage = NetworkImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PnTa.jpg');
    _getImageInfo();
  }

  void _getImageInfo() async {
    NetworkImage _key = await _networkImage.obtainKey(ImageConfiguration());
    _networkImage.load(_key).addListener((ImageInfo i, bool b){
      print('Image size: ${i.image.width} - ${i.image.height}');
      _imageInfo = i;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ImageDetector(
          onTap: (Offset offset){
            if(_imageInfo != null){
              print('Image clicked: ${offset.dx * _imageInfo.image.width} x ${offset.dy * _imageInfo.image.height}');
            }
          },
          image: _networkImage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef void OnTapLocation(Offset offset);

class ImageDetector extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageDetector({Key key, this.onTap, this.image}) : super(key: key);

  final OnTapLocation onTap;
  final ImageProvider image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _onTap(details, context),
      child: Image(image: image),
    );
  }


  void _onTap(TapDownDetails details, BuildContext context) {
    RenderBox getBox = context.findRenderObject();
    Offset local = getBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

    print('Clicked on: ${local.dx / getBox.size.width} - ${local.dy / getBox.size.height}');
    onTap(Offset(local.dx / getBox.size.width, local.dy / getBox.size.height));
  }
}
```

This will return click position between 0.0, 0.0 and 1.0, 1.0, you can get size of the image and get exact location from those.

Edit: updated the code